# foreach with empty data set

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

I am trying to use a foreach statement to display a list ul>li. In case the list has no elements how can i handle that criteria.

```
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($person['CastsMovie'] as $cast): ?>
      <li><?php echo $this->Html->link($cast['Movie']['name'], array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'view', $cast['movie_id'],  'admin' => true), array('escape' => false)); ?> (<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($cast['Movie']['MovieDetail']['release_date'])); ?>)</li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether it is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or not:

```
if ( !empty( $person ) ) {
  foreach ( $person as $cast ) {
    echo "<li>$cast</li>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<li>This play has no cast members.</li>";
}
```

Comment: a simple ( ! $person ) should suffice if boolean is expected !

Comment: @Philip Likely, though I am not 100% certain of how PHP will implicitly handle that so I went with the explicitly clear `empty` function which is documented to work on empty arrays.

Comment: simple `if($person)` it is. PHP will handle empty array all right. the only case for the `empty()` is when variable is not set, but it is set apparently here. -1 though for switching from clean PHP-based template to echoing HTML, making HTML un-highligtable, unindented and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to surround the UL with a check.
Otherwise you end up with an empty "ul" tag which is unnecessary:

```
<?php if (!empty($person['CastsMovie'])) { ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($person['CastsMovie'] as $cast) { ?>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link($cast['Movie']['name'], array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'view', $cast['movie_id'],  'admin' => true), array('escape' => false)); ?> (<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($cast['Movie']['MovieDetail']['release_date'])); ?>)</li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

this means: you check if there are any list elements (in your case CastsMovies to this person) and if so you display the list (ul + li). if not the complete list will be omitted (not just the child li elements).

Answer (score 0):

FIRST, in whatever "controller" you are using, *prepare* your data, to make it fit for the template.

```
foreach($person['CastsMovie'] as $key => $cast) {
  $cast['html_link'] = $this->Html->link($cast['Movie']['name'], 
                                         array('controller' => 'movies', 
                                               'action' => 'view', 
                                               $cast['movie_id'], 
                                               'admin' => true), 
                                         array('escape' => false)
                               ); 
  $cast['html_date'] = date("Y", strtotime($cast['Movie']['MovieDetail']['release_date']));
  $person['CastsMovie'][$key] = $cast;
}
```

Then make your template a sane and readable

```
<?php if($person['CastsMovie']: ?>
<ul>
<?php     foreach($person['CastsMovie'] as $cast): ?>
  <li>
    <?=$cast['html_link']?> (<?=$cast['html_date']?>)
  </li>
<?php     endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: is it a good practice to prepare the data in the controller ?

Comment: The is not just "good". this is just the only acceptable practice, making your templates readable and editable. that is what controllers are for. controller is for the preparing data and view for the displaying it. Look at the resulting template! it is readable at last. Look at the resulting HTML - it is properly indented, letting you to debug whatever HTML errors. Also you have your HTML code readable and editable too

Comment: what about Skinny Controllers and Fat Models ?

Comment: Most weird and bushy part of your code is `$this->Html->link` methos. Which hardly can be moved to model at all.

Comment: Seriously? I think you may be confusing "preparing data" with "preparing markup output", which is what the V does in MVC. Controller should only handle application *logic*, and let the view take care of output formatting. And what the heck is `$this->Html` in a controller anyway? If that's a cake helper, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter well you can move it wherever you want. But if you have to use this "helper" in the template, then your cake is just a piece of crap.

Comment: Wow, a "piece of crap". That is a really strong and valid argument. You got me. I guess the fact that you have to change your *controller* in order to change a CSS class of a link does not bother you at all. Definitely not my common sense though.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter that's why there shouldn't be such a "helper" at all. The real helper function have to return only a *hyperlink.* The rest have to be written in the template, using HTML and CSS.

Comment: A hyperlink is an `<a>` tag, which is HTML, so I'm not getting what you're trying to say here. In addition to that, you must really hate cake, rails and pretty much every other MVC framework out there if you think helpers like this should not exist.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter hell wrong term. URL it is. You *may*, however, use whatever HTML helpers that produce  HTML, but them have to be sane, not to be called with a mile-long code, spoinling the whole point of templates